# How can I use asserts in CodenameOne code?

Tags: codenameone

Using IntelliJ, I put an assert statement into my code. I enabled assertions in the vm, but it completely ignored my assertion. I tried it again in NetBeans, and my assertion statement wouldn't even compile.

How can I use the assert statement in my Codename-one java source?

Answer (score 0):

Assertions are currently unimplemented in [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/), this is an omission that should be fixed.

I added an [issue for this](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1609) for this and it was fixed. It should be available in the next plugin update.